# Using multiple tables with ADO.net and C#

Tags: c#, ado.net, winforms

I've just started working with Visual Studio and C#, and am trying to solve a small problem I have.  I come from a Microsoft Access background, and have quite a bit of experience with database queries and forms.

However, I am currently trying to re-implement an access database with C#, ADO.net, and Windows Forms.  Visual Studio makes it easy to create a form based on one table, but I have not yet found out how to make a form based on data from multiple tables.

Is there a way to do this through the Visual Studio interface?  If not, how do I do it in code?

Any information will be appreciated, including links and tutorials, although I have already looked at a few of these and not understood them.  I can't work out how to convert from displaying data in ASP (which most tutorials seem to use) to displaying records in a list box, or sequentially on a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Master/Detail tutorial from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984462(VS.71).aspx

Hopefully that will get you going in the right direction.

pk

Comment: Thanks for this - this is just what I was after. A simple walk through to explain how to put everything together.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to have look at data access methodologies

---

- [**The ADO.NET Entity Framework Overview**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx)
- [**Windows Forms Object Data Binding**](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040614.htm)
- [**Windows Forms Data Binding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx)

---

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the dataview class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdcwwhez.aspx which provides sorting, additional filtering, derived columns and several other bits of functionality that is similar to the Access query object in some respects.